# How can I turn on Wobbly Windows on Ubuntu Mate 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, compiz, mate

I tried turn on in compizconfig but I does not work.
Any solution or it is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to switch window decorator to Compiz in `mate-tweak`.

[image: MATE Tweak]

Then install CompizConfig Settings Manager

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

and launch it with `ccsm`, confirm usage, enter *wobbly* in search bar, click checkbox near it and confirm disable of **Snapping Windows** plugin:

[image: Wobbly Windows enable]

and enjoy:

[image: Wobbly Windows on Ubuntu MATE in action]

Answer (score 2):

You do not need compizconfig or mate-tweak.
Just Open Ubuntu Software Center, then search for 'Wobbly Windows' and install it. Click on 'Extension Settings' scrool down to Wobbly WIndows and keep it ON.

There you go !
It works for me.