# gnome-panel keeps dying

Tags: gnome, gtk

I'm on Ubuntu 21.10. I use gnome-flashback with Compiz. gnome-panel (version: 3.41.2) keeps crashing for me for some reason. Here's a log file but I can't seem to find what the problem is.

```
Gtk-Message: 14:07:17.772: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"
(gnome-panel:202571): indicator-applet-WARNING **: 14:07:17.936: Binding '<Super>F1' failed!
(gnome-panel:202571): indicator-applet-WARNING **: 14:07:17.937: Binding '<Super>F1' failed!
(gnome-panel:202571): indicator-applet-WARNING **: 14:07:17.938: Binding '<Super>F1' failed!
(gnome-panel:202571): indicator-applet-WARNING **: 14:07:17.964: Binding '<Super>S' failed!
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:07:18.369: Unable to register the object to DBus: An object is already exported for the interface com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar at /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:07:18.369: Unable to register the object to DBus: An object is already exported for the interface com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar at /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:07:18.464: Unable to claim the name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:07:18.464: Unable to claim the name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:07:24.041: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:07:24.041: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
...
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:07:26.503: gtk_window_set_attached_to: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:07:26.503: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:07:26.504: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:07:26.504: gtk_window_set_screen: assertion 'GTK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:07:26.707: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
...
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:10:04.942: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:10:04.942: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (115,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b549a0)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (112,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b54d80)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (120,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b5a1d0)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (99,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b5a5b0)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (118,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b5a990)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.528: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (102,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b5ad70)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.529: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (104,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b815b0)
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:11:06.529: ../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:6776: no accelerator (117,4) installed in accel group (0x55c819556660) for Genericmenuitem (0x55c819b88d80)
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:11:06.613: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
...
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:11:07.160: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:11:07.160: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:11:07.232: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:11:07.232: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:11:07.232: menus_destroyed: assertion 'IS_WINDOW_MENU(wm)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:11:08.079: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:11:08.079: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
...
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:14:37.169: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-panel:202571): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:14:37.228: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'
(gnome-panel:202571): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 14:14:37.228: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Comment: Looks like crash is caused by indicator-appmenu. Do you know how to install debug symbols and get crash stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to fix each warning or error step by step.

1. The below message

   > `Gtk-Message: 14:07:17.772: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"`

   is fixable by installing the [corresponding packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=xapp-gtk3-module) by:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xapps-common libxapp1
   ```
2. Then message

   > `(gnome-panel:202571): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 14:07:18.369: Unable to register the object to DBus: An object is already exported for the interface com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar at /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar`

   should be fixed by installing the [corresponding packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=impish&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar&searchon=contents) by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall plasma-workspace-dev appmenu-registrar
   ```

Then reboot and login to GNOME FlashBack (Compiz) session again.

---

Some IMHO is below.
Really GNOME FlashBack (with either Metacity or Compiz) will not solve usability loss of GNOME Shell in long-time perspective. So you are welcome to [remove it](https://askubuntu.com/q/1233025/66509) and install normally fully traditional stable desktop named [MATE](https://mate-desktop.org/) which is a fork of GNOME 2. See the full list of reasons in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384881/66509).
Installation of MATE is as simple as `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`.

Comment: Is there a reason for installing the dev version of plasma-workspace? It seems to install a boatload of other libs, a long boatload. Hmm...taking -dev off and it seems to install even more! Odd.

Not sure what you mean when you say "usability loss of GNOME Shell". IMHO GNOME Shell has a lot of usability loss compared with gnome2.

Comment: After upgrading and getting my nvidia drivers from System76 reinstalled (they were missing in action) I now have:

Comment: After installing the above and reinstalling my nvidia driver from System76 I now see only errors like:

(gnome-panel:12702): indicator-applet-WARNING **: 08:02:07.934: Binding '<Super>F1' failed!
(gnome-panel:12702): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 08:02:08.430: Unable to register the object to DBus: An object is already exported for the interface com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar at /com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar

(gnome-panel:12702): Indicator-Appmenu-CRITICAL **: 08:02:08.521: Unable to claim the name com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar

Comment: It is really hard to reproduce your problem on some isolated new VM. I tried to provide solution on the file-level, trying to get missed files installed back. I have never seen these Registrar messages before. So you can continue using it as it is or go with plan B - try to use MATE DE as it is configured and installed in Ubuntu MATE.

Comment: I have many mate packages installed. Specifically, I don't have mate-desktop-environment. As my desktop is highly customized I am reluctant to just install it and mess everything up. Will I be able to install it and if it messes everything up, can I uninstall it and expect everything to come back to normal? Also, this is my work desktop so I'll try this on my laptop later tonight. If mate-desktop works well, is there any of the old gnome2 environment I should uninstall?

Comment: Try on fresh VM first if unsure.

Comment: I'm sure a fresh VM will work fine. The real challenge here is to see if it can install in my highly customized environment without totally f-ing it up. IIRC, mate does not honor any application launchers that you have previously installed. If it's just that I have to recreate those, while a PITA, I might move forward with mate destkop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer is to move from old gnome-panel (Gnome2) to something more supported like Mate and mate-panel.